# Why do we need SSE when we have http2 bidirectional streaming?

Tags: http2

This may seem elementary but i didn't find any answers on internet.

My understanding of **SSE** (server sent events) is that data is sent from server to client on a **TCP** connection when the data is available on the server, if the connection is closed, a new connection is opened by the client.

In **http2** bidirectional streaming we are streaming the data from server when it is available and connection is kept open. This does the same as **SSE**.

I am not referring to **http2** server push.

Comment: SSE uses plain text with the specified format (ex: `data:`, `event:`, `id:`). HTTP2 streaming uses binary with no specified format.

Answer (score 1):

In an HTTP/2 connection, you have individual streams. Those streams (except for the push promises) need to get opened by the client to send a HTTP request, then the server can send an answer.

So you still need a stream to be opened by a client, waiting for the server to send some data.

And then the whole connection might break down (just like a HTTP/1.1 connection, or a plain TCP one), which means the client still needs to open a new connection (and open a stream there).

So HTTP/2 doesn't solve anything here which would make SSE superfluous.

As mentioned by Yami Odymel in a comment, the SSE specification also specifies the exact format of the messages being sent.